# How to convert an excel input wrapped in brackets and curly brackets into 1 long row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an entire excel column of different outputs but they all share the same format

> [{"label":"XXXX","value":"YYYY"},{{"label":"zzzzz","value":"QQQQ"}]

When I read each row they are strings, I cannot transform it back into a list or a dictionary. How should I go about removing the string tag and turn it into a dataframe or a callable dictionary?

Comment: 1) upload your excel file or a sample of it.... 2) show us how you want the final dataframe to look like

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made a typo in your string with the second '{':

> [{"label":"XXXX","value":"YYYY"},{**{**"label":"zzzzz","value":"QQQQ"}]

You can use JSON to convert your string into a list:

```py
import json

csv = '[{"label":"XXXX","value":"YYYY"},{"label":"zzzzz","value":"QQQQ"}]'

csv_list = json.loads(csv)
```

> csv_list -> [{'label': 'XXXX', 'value': 'YYYY'}, {'label': 'zzzzz', 'value': 'QQQQ'}]
> csv_list[0] -> {'label': 'XXXX', 'value': 'YYYY'}
> type(csv_list) -> <class 'list'>